# Flutter Assertion failed - Rect argument contained a NaN value

Tags: flutter, dart

I am very new to Flutter / Dart so bare with me.

I am starting to learn Flutter and I have the following situation. Based on the given value within the main.dart I want to generate images.

I have the following code now:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FireChar extends StatelessWidget {

  // The amount of Characters are going to be created
  final double amount; 

  FireChar({this.amount});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) Row(
            children: [
              Image.asset(
                'assets/images/characters/fire.png',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                height: double.maxFinite
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
      height: 75,
    );
  }
}
```

I thought this should actually work. Because when I change the `Image.asset` to a Text Widget it renders perfectly. But when I use the above situation I get an reference error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during paint():
Rect argument contained a NaN value.
'dart:ui/painting.dart':
Failed assertion: line 40 pos 10: '<optimized out>'

Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Image
  file:///Users/*/Documents/Coding/Mobile-Apps/Magic/simulation_game/lib/characters/fire.dart:17:21

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#2      _rectIsValid (dart:ui/painting.dart:40:10)
#3      Canvas.drawImageRect (dart:ui/painting.dart:4283:12)
#4      paintImage (package:flutter/src/painting/decoration_image.dart:575:14)
#5      RenderImage.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/image.dart:391:5)
#6      RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2322:7)
#7      PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#8      RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:142:15)
#9      RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2322:7)
#10     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#11     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2805:15)
#12     RenderFlex.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:1079:7)
#13     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2322:7)
#14     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#15     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2805:15)
#16     RenderFlex.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:1089:7)
#17     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2322:7)
#18     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#19     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:142:15)
#20     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2322:7)
#21     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#22     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2805:15)
#23     RenderFlex.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:1089:7)
#24     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2322:7)
#25     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#26     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2805:15)
#27     RenderFlex.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:1079:7)
#28     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2322:7)
#29     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#30     RenderShiftedBox.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:72:15)
#31     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2322:7)
#32     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#33     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2805:15)
#34     RenderStack.paintStack (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:629:5)
#35     RenderStack.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:639:7)
#36     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2322:7)
#37     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#38     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2805:15)
#39     RenderFlex.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:1079:7)
#40     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2322:7)
#41     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#42     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2805:15)
#43     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:412:5)
#44     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2322:7)
#45     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#46     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:142:15)
#47     _RenderInkFeatures.paint (package:flutter/src/material/material.dart:551:11)
#48     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2322:7)
#49     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#50     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:142:15)
#51     PaintingContext.pushLayer (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:396:12)
#52     RenderPhysicalModel.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1925:15)
#53     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2322:7)
#54     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#55     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:142:15)
#56     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2322:7)
#57     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#58     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:142:15)
#59     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2322:7)
#60     PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:140:11)
#61     PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:100:5)
#62     PipelineOwner.flushPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:978:29)
#63     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:455:19)
#64     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:874:13)
#65     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:319:5)
#66     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#67     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1082:9)
#68     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:865:7)
(elided 6 frames from class _AssertionError, class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)

The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderImage#19a83 relayoutBoundary=up10:
  creator: RawImage ← Semantics ← Image ← Row ← Column ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← FireChar ←
    Container ← Row ← Expanded ← Row ← ⋯
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
  size: Size(1.1984620899082103e+308, 1.7976931348623157e+308)
  image: [28×42]
  height: 1.7976931348623157e+308
  fit: cover
  alignment: Alignment.center
  invertColors: false
  filterQuality: low
This RenderObject has no descendants.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Another exception was thrown: Unsupported operation: Infinity or NaN toInt
       ⢿
Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by Infinity pixels on the bottom.

Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 1.1984620899082103e+308 pixels on the right.

Another exception was thrown: SemanticsNode#15(Rect.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), invisible) (with null) tried to set a non-finite rect.
        
Reloaded 2 of 553 libraries in 234ms.
```

**Question:** Can someone explain me why?

Within Main.dart I have called the Widget like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:simulation_game/characters/fire.dart';
import 'package:simulation_game/maps/battleMap.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'ElementSlam',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  
  // Variables
  double mapX = 0;
  double mapY = 0;
  
  // Game and map settings
  String activeMap = 'battle';

  // Functions
  void restartGame(){}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [ 
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: Stack(
                children: [                 
                  // Map
                  BattleMap(
                    currentMap: activeMap,
                  ),     


                  // Computer - Defense
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 80, 50, 80),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 30, 8),
                                child: const Text(
                                  'DEFENCE',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontFamily: "Games",
                                  ),                          
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: FireChar(
                                  amount: 4,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        )      
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),

                  // Computer 
                  // Column(
                  //   children: [
                  //     Padding(
                  //       padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 80, 0, 0),
                  //       child: Container(
                  //         child: 
                  //         Text(
                  //           'DEFENCE',
                  //           textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  //           style: TextStyle(
                  //             color: Colors.white,
                  //             fontSize: 20,
                  //             fontFamily: "Games",
                  //           ),                          
                  //         ),
                  //       ),
                  //     ),
                  //   ],
                  // ),
                  // Column(
                  //   children: [
                  //       Column(
                  //         children: [
                  //           Container(
                  //             alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
                  //             child: FireChar(),
                  //           ),
                  //           Container(
                  //             alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
                  //             child: ElectricChar(),
                  //           ),
                  //         ]
                  //       ),
                  //   ],
                  // ),
                  // VS TEXT
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment(0,0.05),
                    child: Text(
                      'VS',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 80,
                        fontFamily: "Games",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),         
                ],
              )
            )
          ),          
        ]
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you also post the code of `main.dart` as well?

Comment: Also check out `ListView` class instead of using `for` inside `Column`

Comment: @happy_san Added to the description

Comment: try adding `width: 50` to the code which you've posted in the question and let me know if it works

Comment: @happy_san - yes! You are the best. That was the solution! :) Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you want to place images by the number of for loop not the rows. so what you have to do is that you should generate image widgets multiple times not the row widget. like this:

```
Row(
   children: [
            for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) 
              Image.asset(
                'assets/images/characters/fire.png',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                height: double.maxFinite
              ),
            ],
          )
```